# ol tag doesn't work while iterating li tag inside ol tag using for loop in php

Tags: php, html-lists

I'm iterating li tag using for loop inside ol tag but the ordered list numbers for li tag are not displayed

Here is my code:

```
 <ol style="word-wrap:break-word;">
 <?php    
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {                                                                          
        echo '<li style="margin-left:0px;">'.$TnC1[$i].'</li>';                                             
       }
  ?>
</ol>
```

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out following code snippet.

```
<ol style="word-wrap:break-word;">
 <?php    
    //Start the counter value from 1 instead of 0
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $length; $i++) 
    { 
     //Print the counter value                                                                         
     echo $i.".".$TnC1[$i];                                             
    }
  ?>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the unwanted **,**(**comma**) in for loop and also put closing tag ''.

```
echo '<ol style="word-wrap:break-word;">';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) { 

    echo '<li style="margin-left:0px;">'.$TnC1[$i].'</li>'; 

}
echo '</ol>'
```

Comment: Check your $length and $TnC1 array. I can get you the answer with the available information.